# jQuery + CSS dropdown menu with "tab" style

Tags: css, tabs

I am working on my website and I tried to style the dropdown so it will look like tab.

I did it but there is problem - somehow there are parts of the border in wrong color - why? (tested in FF, Chorme and IE9)

This is an image of my problem:[image]

This is fiddle of my work:
[Fiddle - Example of my work](http://jsfiddle.net/4aevH/)

How can I fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: I can't see what you are speaking of. I'm running Chrome 15.0.865.0 dev on 64-bit Linux.

Comment: You cant see it because very small. did you try to zoom-in?

Comment: That is not a CSS dropdown menu, since you do have JavaScript powering it.

Comment: Well I wrote CSS dropdown menu because the problem caused in CSS and I can only fix it with CSS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly I had an amazing idea and I tried it.

first of all I knew that that problem is the white borders I used.

my idea was: to remove the bottom border I made and instead use background-color - it worked.

here's the new fiddle: [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jnU9U/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Setting the border-bottom to transparent seemed to be messing up the borders and adding little dots at the corners. By removing it it seems to look just fine now: http://jsfiddle.net/4aevH/3/. However if you need the transparent border in there for whatever reason I can figure something else out.

Comment: Your solution doesn't solve everything. If you'll zoom-in you see that there are still 2 dots in wrong color. I wrote my own solution which fixed it all.

Answer (score 0):

If you set the border to transparent or white, she is there and must be rendered, so the corners fail...

**Use this:**

```
border-left:0 none;
border-right:0 none;
border-bottom:0 none;
```

I've tested on your example and it seems to solve your issue! If not, please let me know ;)

Comment: I will write the same answer I wrote to paulGraffix - Your solution doesn't solve everything. If you'll zoom-in you see that there are still 2 dots in wrong color. I wrote my own solution which fixed it all.